# AWSDynamoDB 2.4.9 for Swift 3.0 - [AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression setKeyConditionExpression:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, swift3

Just upgraded to Swift 3.0 (swiftlang-800.0.46.2 clang-800.0.38) and XCode Version 8.0 (8A218a) on OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.5.  Pod install/update of AWSDynamoDB went to 2.4.9.

```
let expression = AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression()
expression.keyConditionExpression = "bn = Test"
```

causes my app to crash with everything that I've tried putting in the string:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression setKeyConditionExpression:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6080000747c0'
```

I was using expression.hashKeyValues for my query before and it worked fine, but that has been removed in the latest version.  I have been using this to model my changes:
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/blob/master/DynamoDBObjectMapper-Sample/Swift/DynamoDBSampleSwift/DDBSearchViewController.swift

Looking for guidance as to whether I'm using keyConditionExpression incorrectly, should be using something else, need to update to something else, or if this error message is a red herring, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look something like this:

```
    let objectMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.defaultDynamoDBObjectMapper()
    let queryExpression = AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression()
    queryExpression.keyConditionExpression = "#hashAttribute = :hashAttributeWithComplexName"
    queryExpression.expressionAttributeNames = ["#hashAttribute": "hashAttribute"]
    queryExpression.expressionAttributeValues = [":hashAttribute": value]
```

This is some header doc which provides a context as to which method performs which operation:

```
/**
 The condition that specifies the key value(s) for items to be retrieved by the Query action. For more information, see [AWSDynamoDBQueryInput keyConditionExpression]

 For example, you may set keyConditionExpression to `hashAttributeName = :hashVal AND rangeAttributeName = :rangeVal` where `hashAttributeName` and `rangeAttributeName` is the attribute name of the hash key and range key respectively. Then you can set `expressionAttributeValues` to `@{@":hashVal" : @"myHashValue", @":rangeVal" : @100}`.

 @see [AWSDynamoDBQueryInput keyConditionExpression]
 @see expressionAttributeNames
 @see expressionAttributeValues
 */
public var keyConditionExpression: String?

/**
 One or more substitution tokens for attribute names in an expression.

 @see [AWSDynamoDBQueryInput expressionAttributeNames]
 */
public var expressionAttributeNames: [String : String]?

/**
 One or more values that can be substituted in an expression.

 @see [AWSDynamoDBQueryInput expressionAttributeValues]
 */
public var expressionAttributeValues: [String : AnyObject]?
```